# How {{ Auth::user()->name }} is able to print username in blade file?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I have been working in default authentication features in laravel..I found in one blade file Auth::user()->name is able to display name stored  in user table..But what i want to know is how it is able display name in blade with an eloquent call.

Comment: `Auth` is the facade to access the auth manager, and `Auth::user` returs the authenticated user associated with the default guard. It is not an eloquent query (not directly anyway) so there's a logical disconnect between assumptions and assumed desired end result.

Comment: guys if any mistake in my question or u didnt understand my question plz let me know ..plz dont down vote .I may lose my account

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use it like this.

`auth()->user()->some_column`

Check your user table in your database and use the appropriate column name.

You can use it in blade file like this.
`{{ auth()->user()->some_column }}`

If you're going to use this in a conditional statement like IF, you can use it like this.

`@if(auth()->user()->some_column)`

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use vanilla php for blade. Just do something like this `{{ Auth::user()->email }}` to get email, `{{ Auth::user()->id }}` to get id or `{{ Auth::user()->some_column }}` to get some_column from user table in database from current authenticated user.

Laravel got a amazing documentation [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade) and somthing good to learn is [laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/) with video tutorials with Jeffrey Way.

Answer (score 0):

It's very late, for for future  -

These steps are supposed to be followed behind-

When you login using `Auth` facade, the `Auth::user()` connects to the default `'users'` table(which can be changed by referring to the documentation) and fetches all the data against the **username or email** whatever you used to authenticate the user.

After that, using `Auth::user()->columnname` retrieves the data from the `columnname` of the respective user (whose username/email was recognized above) and displays it. This data is made available to be used in blade tp be rendered.

The `Auth::user()` disconnects from the database when the user logs out (command followed `Auth::logout()`) and the above steps are repeated for re-login.