# How to get user id in Laravel Blade by JWT package

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-blade

I use JWT, and I want to get user id in Laravel-Blade as follow:

```
<a href="/admin/users/edt/{{auth()->guard('api')->user()->id}}" class="nav-item dropdown-item">Profile</a>
```

but I receive this error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sanayekala_backend\resources\views\admin.blade.php)

Comment: `Auth::user()->id` it's also a good idea to check if there is a user with `Auth::user()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How {{ Auth::user()->name }} is able to print username in blade file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125197/how-authuser-name-is-able-to-print-username-in-blade-file)